# SearchBar error : "App\Entity\Product" object not found by "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ArgumentResolver\EntityValueResolver"

Tags: symfony, searchbar

I am having an issue with my searchBar which is included in the base.html.twig file with a template.

It was working when I was only displaying products with the function findAll, but now I have my own queries and the search does not work anymore.

Clearing the cache did not work.

I am on Symfony 5.5.7 & PHP 8.2.0

ProductRepository

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<Product>
 *
 * @method Product|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Product|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Product[]    findAll()
 * @method Product[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class ProductRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Product::class);
    }

    /**
     * Recherche des produits en fonction du formulaire
     * @return array
     */
    public function search(string $query){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $qb
            ->where('MATCH_AGAINST(p.titre, p.description, p.short_titre) AGAINST (:query boolean)>0')
            ->setParameter('query', $query);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    }

    
   /**
    * @return Product[] Returns an array of Product objects
    */
   public function newProducts(int $page = 1, int $limit = 10)
   {
       $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->where('p.date_publication >= :week_ago')
           ->setParameter('week_ago', new \DateTime('-7 days'))
           ->orderBy('p.titre', 'ASC')
           ->getQuery();
           
           $paginator = new Paginator($query);

           $paginator->getQuery()
                ->setFirstResult($limit * ($page - 1))
                ->setMaxResults($limit);
        
                return $paginator;

   }

   public function jvProducts(int $page = 1, int $limit = 10)
   {
       $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->where('p.categorie = 29')
           ->orderBy('p.titre', 'ASC')
           ->getQuery();
           
           $paginator = new Paginator($query);

           $paginator->getQuery()
                ->setFirstResult($limit * ($page - 1))
                ->setMaxResults($limit);
        
                return $paginator;

   }

   public function figurines(int $page = 1, int $limit = 10)
   {
       $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->where('p.categorie = 23')
           ->orderBy('p.titre', 'ASC')
           ->getQuery();
           
           $paginator = new Paginator($query);

           $paginator->getQuery()
                ->setFirstResult($limit * ($page - 1))
                ->setMaxResults($limit);
        
                return $paginator;

   }

   public function produitsMonde(int $page = 1, int $limit = 10)
   {
       $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->where('p.categorie = 31')
           ->orderBy('p.titre', 'ASC')
           ->getQuery();
           
           $paginator = new Paginator($query);

           $paginator->getQuery()
                ->setFirstResult($limit * ($page - 1))
                ->setMaxResults($limit);
        
                return $paginator;

   }

   public function textiles(int $page = 1, int $limit = 10)
   {
       $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->where('p.categorie = 32')
           ->orderBy('p.titre', 'ASC')
           ->getQuery();
           
           $paginator = new Paginator($query);

           $paginator->getQuery()
                ->setFirstResult($limit * ($page - 1))
                ->setMaxResults($limit);
        
                return $paginator;

   }

//    public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?Product
//    {
//        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
//            ->andWhere('p.exampleField = :val')
//            ->setParameter('val', $value)
//            ->getQuery()
//            ->getOneOrNullResult()
//        ;
//    }
}
```

SearchController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class SearchController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/search', name: 'app_search')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('search/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'SearchController',
        ]);
    }

    public function searchBar(){
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('handleSearch'))
            ->add('query', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' => 'Entrez un mot-clé'
                ]
                ])
            ->add('recherche', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
                    ]
            ])
        ->getForm();
    return $this->render('_partials/_searchBar.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
            
    }

    #[Route('/handleSearch', name: 'handleSearch')]
    public function handleSearch(Request $request, ProductRepository $productRepository)
    {
        $query = $request->request->all('form')['query'];
       
        if($query){
            
            $products = $productRepository->search($query);
        }
        return $this->render('_partials/_searchIndex.html.twig', [
            'products' => $products
        ]);
    }
}
```

Entity
Product.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProductRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Index(name: 'product', columns: ['titre', 'description', 'short_titre'], flags: ["fulltext"] )]
class Product
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $titre = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $slug = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $description = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?float $prix = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $quantite = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?float $remise = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $dimensions = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?bool $disponibilite = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'products')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Categorie $categorie = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'produit', targetEntity: Images::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete:"CASCADE")]
    
    private Collection $images;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Couleurs::class, mappedBy: 'product')]
    private Collection $couleurs;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'products')]
    private ?Fabricants $fabricant = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'products')]
    private ?Marques $marque = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Matieres::class, inversedBy: 'products')]
    private Collection $matieres;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Personnages::class, inversedBy: 'products')]
    private Collection $personnages;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'products')]
    private ?SousCategorie1 $sousCategorie1 = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'products')]
    private ?SousCategorie2 $sousCategorie2 = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'products')]
    private ?Univers $univers = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'products')]
    private ?SousUnivers $sousUnivers = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $avis = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $short_titre = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $date_publication = null;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->couleurs = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->matieres = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->personnages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    public function setTitre(string $titre): static
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): static
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): static
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrix(): ?float
    {
        return $this->prix;
    }

    public function setPrix(float $prix): static
    {
        $this->prix = $prix;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuantite(): ?int
    {
        return $this->quantite;
    }

    public function setQuantite(int $quantite): static
    {
        $this->quantite = $quantite;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRemise(): ?float
    {
        return $this->remise;
    }

    public function setRemise(?float $remise): static
    {
        $this->remise = $remise;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDimensions(): ?string
    {
        return $this->dimensions;
    }

    public function setDimensions(?string $dimensions): static
    {
        $this->dimensions = $dimensions;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isDisponibilite(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->disponibilite;
    }

    public function setDisponibilite(bool $disponibilite): static
    {
        $this->disponibilite = $disponibilite;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategorie(): ?Categorie
    {
        return $this->categorie;
    }

    public function setCategorie(?Categorie $categorie): static
    {
        $this->categorie = $categorie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Images>
     */
    public function getImages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    public function addImage(Images $image): static
    {
        if (!$this->images->contains($image)) {
            $this->images->add($image);
            $image->setProduit($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeImage(Images $image): static
    {
        if ($this->images->removeElement($image)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($image->getProduit() === $this) {
                $image->setProduit(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Couleurs>
     */
    public function getCouleurs(): Collection
    {
        return $this->couleurs;
    }

    public function addCouleur(Couleurs $couleur): static
    {
        if (!$this->couleurs->contains($couleur)) {
            $this->couleurs->add($couleur);
            $couleur->addProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCouleur(Couleurs $couleur): static
    {
        if ($this->couleurs->removeElement($couleur)) {
            $couleur->removeProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFabricant(): ?Fabricants
    {
        return $this->fabricant;
    }

    public function setFabricant(?Fabricants $fabricant): static
    {
        $this->fabricant = $fabricant;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMarque(): ?Marques
    {
        return $this->marque;
    }

    public function setMarque(?Marques $marque): static
    {
        $this->marque = $marque;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Matieres>
     */
    public function getMatieres(): Collection
    {
        return $this->matieres;
    }

    public function addMatiere(Matieres $matiere): static
    {
        if (!$this->matieres->contains($matiere)) {
            $this->matieres->add($matiere);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMatiere(Matieres $matiere): static
    {
        $this->matieres->removeElement($matiere);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Personnages>
     */
    public function getPersonnages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->personnages;
    }

    public function addPersonnage(Personnages $personnage): static
    {
        if (!$this->personnages->contains($personnage)) {
            $this->personnages->add($personnage);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePersonnage(Personnages $personnage): static
    {
        $this->personnages->removeElement($personnage);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSousCategorie1(): ?SousCategorie1
    {
        return $this->sousCategorie1;
    }

    public function setSousCategorie1(?SousCategorie1 $sousCategorie1): static
    {
        $this->sousCategorie1 = $sousCategorie1;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSousCategorie2(): ?SousCategorie2
    {
        return $this->sousCategorie2;
    }

    public function setSousCategorie2(?SousCategorie2 $sousCategorie2): static
    {
        $this->sousCategorie2 = $sousCategorie2;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUnivers(): ?Univers
    {
        return $this->univers;
    }

    public function setUnivers(?Univers $univers): static
    {
        $this->univers = $univers;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSousUnivers(): ?SousUnivers
    {
        return $this->sousUnivers;
    }

    public function setSousUnivers(?SousUnivers $sousUnivers): static
    {
        $this->sousUnivers = $sousUnivers;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAvis(): ?string
    {
        return $this->avis;
    }

    public function setAvis(?string $avis): static
    {
        $this->avis = $avis;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getShortTitre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->short_titre;
    }

    public function setShortTitre(?string $short_titre): static
    {
        $this->short_titre = $short_titre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDatePublication(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date_publication;
    }

    public function setDatePublication(\DateTimeInterface $date_publication): static
    {
        $this->date_publication = $date_publication;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I am trying to search for a product with words included in its title, description or short title using the Match Against function. The search should get me to a new page with all the results or a message telling no results were found.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace:

```php
->where('MATCH_AGAINST(p.titre, p.description, p.short_titre) AGAINST (:query boolean)>0')
```

with:

```php
->where('MATCH(p.titre, p.description, p.short_titre) AGAINST (:query boolean) > 0')
```

in `App\Repository\ProductRepository::search()` method (in `ProductRepository.php` file on 113 line)?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, unfortunately it's not the issue, I had this code written this way and it worked, but I still tried just to see if there will be any changes but no.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved the problem, I think it was due to the route I put a the top of my ProductController, I had #[Route('/', name: 'products_')] but I think it went wrong because this is also the route for  my homepage, now it works

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

#[Route('/produits', name: 'products_')]
class ProductController extends AbstractController
{

    public function __construct(private EntityManagerInterface $em){}

    #[Route('/jeux-vidéos', name: 'jv')]
    public function jv(Request $request): Response
    {
        $page = $request->query->getInt('page', 1);
        $limit = $request->query->getInt('limit',10);

        $products = $this->em->getRepository(Product::class)->jvProducts($page, $limit);


        return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', [
            'products' => $products,
            'limit' => $limit,
            'page' => $page
        ]);
    }


    #[Route('/figurines', name: 'figurines')]
    public function figurines(Request $request): Response
    {
        $page = $request->query->getInt('page', 1);
        $limit = $request->query->getInt('limit',10);

        $products = $this->em->getRepository(Product::class)->figurines($page, $limit);


        return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', [
            'products' => $products,
            'limit' => $limit,
            'page' => $page
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/produits-du-monde', name: 'produits_du_monde')]
    public function produitsMonde(Request $request): Response
    {
        $page = $request->query->getInt('page', 1);
        $limit = $request->query->getInt('limit',10);

        $products = $this->em->getRepository(Product::class)->produitsMonde($page, $limit);


        return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', [
            'products' => $products,
            'limit' => $limit,
            'page' => $page
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/textiles', name: 'textiles')]
    public function textiles(Request $request): Response
    {
        $page = $request->query->getInt('page', 1);
        $limit = $request->query->getInt('limit',10);

        $products = $this->em->getRepository(Product::class)->textiles($page, $limit);


        return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', [
            'products' => $products,
            'limit' => $limit,
            'page' => $page
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/{slug}', name: 'details')]
    public function detailProduit(Product $product): Response
    {
        return $this->render('product/detail.html.twig', [
            'product' => $product
        ]);
    }
}
```